# Is there a way to find out that a task has been cleared via airflow UI?

Tags: python, airflow

How can I make certain logic work at the moment when the task is cleared through the airflow UI?

Or how can I determine at the time of running task that it was restarted due to the fact that it was cleared through airflow UI?

I looked at the triggers and the available callbacks, there are different ones, but not the ones I need.

So far I have found a way only by analyzing logs or using Xcom, but these solutions are not very convenient.